# Category under which smote falls into

Tags: pandas, data-mining, data-cleaning

So, I have a tree diagram where different algorithms are present. For example XGBoost falls under gradient boosting, decision tree and random forest comes under classification and many more. I would like to know under which category does SMOTE come into.[image: taxonomy of the different algorithms used]

Answer (score 2):

SMOTE should not appear on there, as it is a method for synthesizing new points, not for making predictions based on existing features.

[Also, the need for SMOTE is contested.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he)

Finally, I dispute the grouping. Deep learning and neural networks can be used as classifiers just as random forests can be. I would be skeptical of the source where that image originated.

Comment: oh thank you, actually it is a tree diagram that I've been working on. So you're telling me to put ANN under classification as well ?

Comment: Isn’t classification a form of prediction?